# Compare user input to an existing dictionary in Python3 and keep getting KeyError

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to compare user input to an existing dictionary and keep getting value errors. I have repeatedly searched and changed the code but keep getting the same type of error. any ideas on how to solve this. I just want to verify that a username and password exist in the dictionary. Error I am getting:

> File "C:\Users\jeff\Desktop\JAMGR\jeff\theCards.py", line 262, in login
>       if NAME == users[NAME] and PASSWORD == users[PASSWORD]:
>   KeyError: 'jeff001'

```
def login(entUsername, entPassword):
    NAME = entUsername.get()
    PASSWORD = entPassword.get()
    #print(NAME, PASSWORD) this was to test the stored values (actually works)
    userList()
    if NAME == users[NAME] and PASSWORD == users[PASSWORD]:
        cardCreator()

    else:
        existingUser()

'''Checks their credentials against the ones we have in the data base'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are checking your dictionary incorrectly. Assuming your dictionary looks like this. You can't get the key by using the value (with simple a operation) since dictionaries are not designed that way. What you want to do is.

```
d = {'username': 'password'}
NAME = 'username'
PASSWORD = 'password'

if PASSWORD == d.get(NAME):
    # Correct ...
else:
    # incorrect ...
```

I use `d.get(NAME)` as apposed to `d[NAME]` because if no key exists within the dictionary that matches what is given, you get an error. However `dict.get()` returns `None` if no matching value is found which results in False for your if statement.

Comment: thanks for the help i am new to python and did not even realize i was comparing the same values  this is the code that finally worked                   if PASSWORD == users[NAME]

Answer (score 1):

Check in the dictionary, and make sure that your dictionary is layed out as it is supposed to be... If i were using your app, this is ***exactly*** how your dictionary should look like:

```
users = {
    "Viraj": "Viraj",
    "myPassword": "myPassword"
}
```

notice how the dictionary `key`, and `value` are identical, that may be the issue!.